# Array content, stored in variable, gets cut off

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to put content into an array. The content, around 100 urls, is already stored in a variable that I call `$arraycontents` which is formatted with ",". For some reason the array get cuts of when I do this but it works when I put in the urls manually. Very annoying problem.

Here is the code:

```
$arraycontents =  '"http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=' . implode('","http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=',$matches[0]). '"';

$urls = array($arraycontents);
```

in the error message I get it looks like the array is cut off.

Comment: .. What? All you are doing is passing a string into an' array. - Also please include the error message....

Comment: I'm afraid I couldn't post the warning since it contains urls.

Comment: ...you could have replaced them with `example.com` if actuals aren't supposed to be known. @Carl-JohanHagberg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$matches[0]` contains "urls" already an array, so prefix all with (if I guess right what OP wants)

```
$urls = array_map(function($m) { 
   return 'http://archive.org/wayback/available?url='.$m;
},$matches[0]);
```